# SSH using pem file asking for password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, file-permissions

I've been installing my production ENV on EC2, ubuntu.
After couple of days playing with stuff (specifically) changing folder permissions, I suddenly realized, something went wrong with my default ubuntu user, and now when I am trying to

```
ssh -i production.pem ubuntu@ec2----amazonaws.com
```

It asks me for a password.
I've tried modifying my ubuntu folder permission recursively back (or not back) to ubuntu, but it didn't work:

```
sudo chmod ubuntu:ubuntu .
```

Any idea what have I changed and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:
SSH to the account using a different account and switched to the ubuntu user,

```
sudo su ubuntu
```

Made sure my ubuntu home folder is owned solely by the user:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
```

Gave all permissions to for the users to do anything:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

And (this is the most important part..), changed the .ssh folder correctly:

```
chmod 600 authorized_keys 
chmod 600 id_rsa
chmod 644 id_rsa.pub
chmod 644 known_hosts
```

Answered my own, but kept for future reference.. (It took me a while to figure:)
Good look.